# angular directive not work properly when changes made dynamically through `link` property

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a custom directive. Then I tried to add a submit button into it through `link` property. But that submit button is not working.
On the other hand the submit button added through `template` property is working fine.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
 .directive("mydir", ['$compile', function($compile){
     return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<form ng-submit="submitMe()">'
                    + '    <input type="submit" value="template submit" />'
                    + '</form>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.append('<input type="submit" value="link submit" />');
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.submitMe = function(){
                    window.alert("SUBMITTED");
                }
            }]
        };
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
    <mydir></mydir>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afzalex/qa2qg1v1/6/)

How can I make the changes made in DOM from `link` property work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `button` outside the `form` element, which wouldn't fire form `submit` event, as its outside a `form` element.

`button` element should be inside form element, then only clicking on submit `button` of `form`  will fire submit.

**Code**

```
element.find('form').append('<input type="submit" />');
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bosu02gj/)